# Leaflet Routing Machine show option doesn't work

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am adding route to the map and I want to hide instruction (turn left, turn right etc.) but I want to show them later. As I can see there is parameter `show` for that. If I set `show: false` I see white squares instead of istructions which is ok, the problem is that I can't show instructions then by clicking on that squares, no interaction with them at all.

```
L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(54.736985, 55.980878),
    L.latLng(54.732798, 55.969934),
  ],
  show: false,
}).addTo(map)
```

There is nothing wrong here I guess. What can it be then?

Comment: could you create a minimal working example with your code so we can help you in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet Routing Machine plugin has no built in method to toggle itinerary display.

One very elementary solution would be to add transparent `div` element with absolute postion on the top of `L.Routing.control` container and attach `onclick` event function to it. This function then toggles itinerary display:

```
<style>
  .legendClickArea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var map = L.map('map');

  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var wayPoint1 = L.latLng(57.74, 11.94);
  var wayPoint2 = L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949);

  var bounds = L.latLngBounds(wayPoint1, wayPoint2); 

  var myRouting = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [wayPoint1, wayPoint2],
      routeWhileDragging: true,
      show: false
  });

  myRouting.addTo(map);

  var itineraryShown = false;

  var controlContainer = myRouting.getContainer();
  var legendClickArea = document.createElement("DIV");

  legendClickArea.classList.add('legendClickArea');
  controlContainer.appendChild(legendClickArea);

  legendClickArea.onclick = function() {
    if (itineraryShown)
      myRouting.hide();
    else {
      myRouting.show();
    }
    itineraryShown = !itineraryShown;
  };      
</script>
```

This `div` element can then be embellished with various bells and whistless.

Answer (score 0):

When we install leaflet , in nodemodules there is a css file given by leaflet, use that css file or you can also use cnd

Comment: This does not answer the question.